# How can i get 4 maximum value from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to fetch some states and their value from database by this query

```
SELECT state, COUNT(*) c FROM user_track WHERE day  BETWEEN '16' and '24' AND 
viewed='aniket27' GROUP BY state HAVING c > 0;
```

Which gives me a result like this->

[this is how query look likes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpWxp.png)

then using while loop i add all the data into array

```
$ar = array();
while( $fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$ar[] = $fetch; }
```

This is how array looks after printing.

[this is how array looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZbDo.png)

Now i want to get four states with maximum count value in a new array and rest state and their values into another array how can i achieve this?

here is what I've tried

```
function maxN(array $numbers, $n)
{
    $maxHeap = new SplMaxHeap;
    foreach($numbers as $number) {
        $maxHeap->insert($number);
    }
    return iterator_to_array(
        new LimitIterator($maxHeap, 0, $n)
    );
}
print_r( maxN( $a, 4 ) );
```

One more thing why does my array look like multi dimension?

Comment: post code, not pictures.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're after here

Comment: @Dale i want to get 4 maximum value from the array

Comment: why not just add a limit to the querry?

Comment: @Dagon because I'm counting the row of states, i don't think i can use limit there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort your array

```
usort($ar, function($a, $b){
    return strnatcmp($a['c'], $b['c']);
});
```

and then slice it

```
$ar2 = array_slice($ar, 0, 4);
```

Alternatively you could alter your SQL

```
SELECT state, COUNT(*) c FROM user_track
WHERE day BETWEEN '16' and '24' 
AND viewed = 'aniket27' 
GROUP BY state HAVING c > 0
ORDER BY c DESC
```

and your data will come out in the right order